# How to write file locations as string in python

Tags: python

I cant seem to write something like : "C:\Users\alon4\Desktop\Learning Material\Odyssey\Lab a2\Magnetism\data"
As a string to print or otherwise, i think its something to do with the slashes

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 ways :

**1)** Either use `r` (raw strings) before the actual string : 
For example : `r"C:\Users\alon4\Desktop\Learning Material\Odyssey\Lab a2\Magnetism\data"`

**2)** Or use `//` like:
For example : `"C:\\Users\\alon4\\Desktop\\Learning Material\\Odyssey\\Lab a2\\Magnetism\data"`

**3)** Use slashes: `"C:/Users/alon4/Desktop/Learning Material/Odyssey/Lab a2/Magnetism/data"`
(As suggested by Óscar López)